# In Airflow Pool Dagrun status is scheduled but in List Dag Run Dagrun status is running

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver, airflow-taskflow, airflow-api

I am testing Airflow pool, created a pool with 2 slots, whenever i run a dag more than 2 times, 2 dagruns start and remaining in scheduled state, but for same dag when i check it on grid view all dagruns status shown as running.

Kindle help me here what is happening, how can this be resolved so that both side i can see same status.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up DAG runs and tasks. A DAG Run in the running state will usually have tasks in a variety of states, including running, scheduled, success, and failed. Until all tasks in the DAG run have reached a terminal state, the DAG will be in "running". Airflow Pools operate on tasks, not DAG Runs, so what you're seeing there is task statuses.